# Iterating over a Chef array and using key in Ohai lookup

Tags: loops, attributes, chef-infra, ohai-gem

I'm iterating over an array, and would like to use the key as part of the logic to lookup an Ohai value.  In my particular case, I'm attempting to `source` each defined user's .bashrc if triggered from a previous resource.

Ohai structure:

`"etc": {
    "passwd": {
      "root": {
        "dir": "/root",
        "gid": 0,
        "uid": 0,
        "shell": "/bin/bash",
        "gecos": "root"
      },
    ...
      "foo": {
        "dir": "/home/foo",
        "gid": 501,
        "uid": 501,
        "shell": "/bin/bash",
        "gecos": ""
      },
    ...`

So as I loop through, I am trying to do something like:

`node['my_cookbook']['managed_users'].each do |usr|
  bash 'reload_shell' do
    code "source #{node['etc']['passwd'][usr]['dir']}/.bashrc"
    action :nothing
  end
end`

I've tried also using `['usr']`, `[#{usr}]`, and `["usr"]` notations, as well as escaping quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over a hash in ruby and access the key you can do:

```
node['my_cookbook']['managed_users'].each do |usr,props|
  bash 'reload_shell' do
    code "source #{node['etc']['passwd'][usr]['dir']}/.bashrc"
    action :nothing
  end
end
```

If you don't care about the key or the values under it, replace the corresponding variable by `_` i.e. in your case:

```
node['my_cookbook']['managed_users'].each do |usr,_|
  bash 'reload_shell' do
    code "source #{node['etc']['passwd'][usr]['dir']}/.bashrc"
    action :nothing
  end
end
```

Without doing this, you get the full underlying hash, so your `usr` var is

```
{
  "root": {
    "dir": "/root",
    "gid": 0,
    "uid": 0,
    "shell": "/bin/bash",
    "gecos": "root"
}
```

instead of being just "root".

Side note: sourcing works for the current shell, within a bash resource the shell is spawned, command executed and the shell is closed. Sourcing a file will have no effect (unless there's a complex processus inside the .bash_rc doing something, this won't affect the system nor the chef run)

Comment: I've upvoted you for your explanation of sourcing, thanks!  However, I'm still seeing a problem `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass` using the |usr,_| notation.

Comment: It was not part of your original question, this mean there's something missing or a typo in the attributes names or that the user your're targeting does not exist

Comment: Just to close the loop on my undefined method issue, I needed to include an ohai "reload" resource and set my paths using lazy attribution.   https://docs.chef.io/resource_ohai.html https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#lazy-attribute-evaluation

Comment: If the users are created in the same, indeed you need to reload ohai for the expected users to be present in the node attributes.